# pkill which waits

Tags: command-line, kill

Is there a pkill-like tool which does this:

1. send signal to all matching processes
2. wait N seconds until the processes have terminated
3. if all processes have terminated, nice: exit
4. if some processes have not terminated send SIGKILL

For me it is important that the tool waits until the processes have really terminated.

I know that it is quite easy to do this in my favourite scripting language, but in this case it would be very nice if I use a tool which already exists.

This needs to run on SuSE-Linux and Ubuntu.

Comment: Before and after the wait, how would one determine that the list of PIDs corresponds to the same set of processes (and weren't recycled)?
Alternatively, how would one determine that the matched command names before and after corresponds to the same processes? Even if you save (command_name, PID) tuples, one can't be 100% sure that these are "correct" both before and after the wait.  There's a inherent race-condition here.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, you are right. There will be some guessing involved. And this means it is not a 100% reliable solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no “standard” command which provides the behaviour you’re after. However, on Debian and derivatives, you can use [`start-stop-daemon`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dpkg/start-stop-daemon.8)’s `--stop` action with the `--retry` option:

```
start-stop-daemon --stop --oknodo --retry 15 -n daemontokill
```

will send `SIGTERM` to all processes named `daemontokill`, wait up to 15s for them to stop, then send `SIGKILL` to all remaining processes (from the initial selection), and wait another 15s for them to die. It will exit with status 0 if there was nothing to kill or all the processes stopped, 2 if some processes were still around after the second timeout.

There are a number of options to match processes in various ways, see the documentation (linked above) for details. You can also provide a more detailed schedule with varying timeouts.

`start-stop-daemon` is part of the `dpkg` package so it’s always available on Debian systems (and derivatives). Some non-`.deb` distributions make the package available too; for example, [openSUSE Leap 42](https://software.opensuse.org/package/dpkg) has it. It’s quite straightforward to build on other platforms:

```
git clone https://salsa.debian.org/dpkg-team/dpkg.git 
cd dpkg
autoreconf -fi && ./configure && make
```

You’ll need `autoconf`, `automake`, `libtool`, `gettext`. Once the build is finished you’ll find `start-stop-daemon` in the `utils` directory.

Comment: I need to support Ubuntu and SuSE. It seems that `start-stop-daemon` is not available for SUSE :-(

Comment: Right, it’s not available on SuSE, but it’s fairly easy to build (see [the source code](https://salsa.debian.org/dpkg-team/dpkg/tree/master/utils)).

Comment: A solution without building (even if it is easy) would be nice :-)

Comment: Is an openSUSE Leap package any use to you?

Comment: Try `killall procname; sleep 15; killall -9 procname`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `timeout` command with `killall -w`

e.g:

```
# timeout 3 killall -vws2 $PROCESS_NAME || killall -vws9 $PROCESS_NAME
```

`timeout` will "timeout" after 3 secends and will exit with error code, which then you catch with `||` and then run `killall -s9` to force the kill.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own script that will fulfil your case. Following this post [useless use of kill -9](http://web.archive.org/web/20080610070315/http://sial.org/howto/shell/kill-9/) and source [reallykill](http://web.archive.org/web/20080213192428if_/http://sial.org:80/howto/shell/kill-9/reallykill)

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# $Id: reallykill,v 1.2 2004/10/11 09:36:48 jmates Exp $
#
# The author disclaims all copyrights and releases this script into the
# public domain.
#
# Kills the specified processes by starting with the TERM signal and
# only if necessary working up to the violent KILL signal. For more
# information, see:
#
# http://sial.org/howto/shell/kill-9/

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "usage: `basename $0` pid [pid ..]" >&2
  exit 100
fi

cycle_kill () {
  PID=$1
  RETVAL=0

  for signal in "TERM" "INT" "HUP" "KILL"; do
    kill -$signal $PID
    RETVAL=$?
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && break
    echo "warning: kill failed: pid=$PID, signal=$signal" >&2
    sleep 1
  done

  return $RETVAL
}

for pid in "$@"; do
  cycle_kill $pid
done
```

So you can just download script to your bin directory:

```
 curl http://web.archive.org/web/20080213192428if_/http://sial.org:80/howto/shell/kill-9/reallykill > $HOME/bin/killwait && chmod +x $HOME/bin/killwait
```

I would use this that way:

```
ping -q localhost &
killwait `pidof ping`
```

Maybe you would like to change order of signals with INT as first, so you would have output with summary of ping command. Provided command does not wait if KILL signal succeed but it should work as process will be killed by system.